# Excel import from csv file to convert

Tags: java, excel, apache, import, apache-poi

Im having difficulty with using Apache POI API. Im trying to import an excel them only select certain rows and cells to extract from the import. Im currently able to import, but i cant extract certain cell. Here is code:

```
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ExcelReader {
    public static final String path = "C:/Users/xxxx/Documents/import testing.xlsx";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {

        // Create a workbook with data from excel file
        Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(path));

        // Save sheets from workbook
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        // Make sure the data is saved in string format using a data formatter
        DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();

        // Iterate through cells and columns, printing their content
        System.out.println("\n\nThe content of the excel file: " + path + "\n");
        String cellContent;
        for (Row row: sheet) {
            for(Cell cell: row) {
                cellContent = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);
                if(cellContent == null || cellContent.trim().isEmpty()){
                    // Give the empty cells the content "empty", to make it easy to filter out later on
                    cellContent = "empty";
                }
                System.out.print(cellContent + "\t");
            }
            CellReference cellReference = new CellReference("A11");
            XSSFRow rowT = sheet.getRow(cellReference.getRow());
            if (rowT != null) {
                XSSFCell cell = rowT.getCell(cellReference.getCol());
            }
            System.out.println();

        }
        // Close the connection to the workbook
        workbook.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: `Row row: sheet` and `Cell cell: row` look suspicious. Are you sure your code compiles?

Comment: I have issue with "XSSFRow rowT = sheet.getRow(cellReference.getRow());" Code dosent compile

Comment: thanks in advance for any help

Comment: @Ivan: There is nothing suspicious on `Java`'s  [For-Each loop syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/foreach.html).

Answer (score 0):

Changing Workbook to XSSFWorkbook and Sheet to XSSFSheet seems to fix the compilation issue.

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new File(path));
```

and

```
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
```

Comment: Thanks this did fix the compilation issue. However im trying to only get cell "A11" from the import, currently returning all. Can you help with this?

Comment: I used CellReference from apache POI api, but it dont seem to extract only that

Answer (score 0):

try with this for get "A11" cell

```
XSSFCell cell = sheet.getRow(10).getCell(0); // 10 = id of the 11th row, 0 = id of the 1st (A) column
```

or

```
XSSFCell cell = sheet.getRow(10).getCell(CellReference.convertColStringToIndex("A"));
```

create cell reference for B12

```
CellReference cr = new CellReference("B12");
row = mySheet.getRow(cr.getRow());
cell = row.getCell(cr.getCol());
```

Comment: Thanks, what if i wanted to get more columns like say "B12". How would i add all those params?